# Iterating over substrings of equal size

Tags: ruby, string, slice

I want to convert my String object to Enumerable of its 1-sized substrings (not chars), how can I do this efficiently in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"xyzzy".split(//) => ["x", "y", "z", "z", "y"]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.9 (and 1.8.7) you can use each_char to reliably iterate over the characters of a string, including proper handling of multi-byte chars and stuff. In earlier releases, each_char does not exist and indexing will return byte codes rather than single char strings. In this case, you can use

```
"abcdefg".split(//u)
```

which will split the string in a UTF-8 aware way.

There's some nice discussion [here](http://billsix.blogspot.com/2007/11/iteration-over-strings-in-ruby.html).

Comment: To index individual characters in pre-1.9 Ruby, you can either do "hello"[0].chr or "hello"[0,1].

Comment: As long as they aren't multi-byte :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but there's no difference between a character and a string of 1 character in Ruby.

```
'hello world'.each_char {|c| puts "substring is #{c}"}
```

Comment: Heh, was about to say the same but my roommate distracted me. =)

Comment: Yes there is a difference; "xyzzy"[0] => 120

Comment: In 1.9.1 this will work. In earlier versions, each_char doesn't work and chars are ints.

Comment: @Dave 1.8.7 has String#each_char too.

Comment: @wombie: 
1. That isn't true anymore as of Ruby 1.9
2. It still doesn't mean a character was different than a one-character string — it's just that String#[] used to return a Fixnum. You have to do "xyzzy"[0].chr to get the appropriate character — which is a one-character string!

Comment: As I said, chars were never really ints (just one operator worked that way, and Matz considered it a mistake) and each_char works fine in 1.8.7.